# Select exactly that div with specific class which is offset.top

Tags: jquery, html

I have this situation:

HTML:

```
<div class="select">Text</div>
<div class="select">Text</div>
<div class="select">Text</div>
<div class="select">Text</div>
```

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (wScroll > $('.select').offset().top) {
        $('.select').css('color','red');
    }
});
```

and when I scroll of course it selects all divs with class .element, but what I want is to target only that div.select which is offset().top = 0, not others.

Comment: *"what I want is to target only that div.select which is offset().top = 0"* Can you expand on that? It doesn't make a lot of sense. Nearly any value of `wScroll` will be `> 0`. Can you explain in different terms which `.select` you want to target? (E.g., the first one showing in the viewport, or...?)

Comment: I meant that when the div.select is scrolled to the top of viewport I want to change only its text color, not other divs with the same class which are below. I could use ids, but in my case it would be more practical to leave it only with class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a marker class, remove it when something scrolls, and then add it to the first `.select` element whose `offset().top` is `>= wScroll`:

```js
// Create a bunch of div.select
var n;
for (n = 0; n < 100; ++n) {
  $("<div class=select>" + n + "</div>").appendTo(document.body);
}

// Make the top one always red
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  $(".select.top").removeClass("top");
  $(".select").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.offset().top >= wScroll) {
      $this.addClass("top");
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.top {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You could use `$this.offset().top + $this.height()` to match the first one even if it's only partially-visible:

```js
// Create a bunch of div.select
var n;
for (n = 0; n < 100; ++n) {
  $("<div class=select>" + n + "</div>").appendTo(document.body);
}

// Make the top one always red
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  $(".select.top").removeClass("top");
  $(".select").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.offset().top + $this.height() >= wScroll) {
      $this.addClass("top");
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.top {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```